# When to use a Sigmoid function and when to use ReLu in a Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

Can someone please refer a good article explaining why we use a Sigmoid activation in the final layer of a neural network and a ReLu activation in the middle layers and input layer while building a Convolutional Neural Network? I am not getting how that results in the right output.

Answer (score 3):

`Relu` solves the gradient vanishing problem and stops the inactive neurons. Using `Sigmoid` in output layer because its range is (0, 1) and it can represent the probability of binary class. When you are doing multi-classification, it is more appropriate to use `Softmax` function.

Maybe you need to read more materials, you can refer to [CS231n](http://cs231n.github.io/). Thanks.